# any special considerations when using gc under mingw32 within a dll

Tags: mingw, boehm-gc

I'm using gc in mingw32 project, and I'm encountering the following problem:
when the program is linked statically, there is no problem, and the program works OK. However, after moving certain components to a dll, the program crashed.
Any advice?
Regards,
bostjanv

Comment: Is the dll available at runtime? On Windows, you should place the dll you linked to next to the executable (or at least have it in PATH). Otherwise you get a crash (or a system error dialog, depending on the configuration of your executable).

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your response. I checked whether libgc-1.dll was in a directory
declared in PATH, and the answer is yes. I even copied it to the same
directory as the one .exe resides in. However, the result is the same.

I checked the mingw32 lib directory, and noticed that there are two
gc libraries, libgc.a, and libgc.dll.a. I tried both of them in building
my dll; but the result is always the same: the program crashes.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

boehm-gc needs to know the data root to scan, each .dll has own data section thus it should be registered somehow. Typically it should be registered automatically (including for mingw32, internal GC_register_dynamic_libraries function is responsible for roots discovery in .dlls and registering). To see which data roots are registered, insert GC_gcollect() and GC_print_static_roots() calls after your .dll is loaded.
If your are running boehm-gc on a Windows 10 host, please ensure that your libgc-1.dll has the [patch](https://github.com/ivmai/bdwgc/pull/219) that fixes handling of .dll sections with PAGE_WRITECOPY flag.